# Limiting UIActivityViewController share extension activities

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` with several custom UIActivityProviders.  My providers return `NSString`, `UIImage`, and custom data objects.  I exclude activities I don't want to share by setting `UIActivityViewController excludedActivityTypes` and Apple's Built-in Activity Types.

The thing I don't like are apps that appear on the presented UIActivityViewController that are not build in activity types.  I'm assuming these appear because the apps have informed iOS 8 they can handle text and image data.  Examples are Flickr, Evernote, and FaceBook's share extension. These activities have their own activity URL type that I don't want to hard code to.

The reason I don't want these apps in my activity sharing is most don't work properly, ending up giving my users a bad experience and likely blaming my app for poor implementation.  The reality is that these apps don't handle the data they claim they can.  For example, Evernote always just presents a empty post dialog. Some, like Facebook's share extension even log errors if they can't handle the data type (really?).

**Is it possible to block all 3rd party sharing extensions?**

If the answer is no, it seems I have only 2 options:

- Only share with Apple's built in activities and my custom activities
- Allow 3 party extensions to screw up the hand off
- Wrap all my content in a custom class so it's not recognizable to extensions.  This generates a logged error from Facebook

The difficulty comes from `initWithPlaceholderItem:(id)placeholderItem`.  I pass back a generic NSString or UIImage which the extensions say they can handle but often don't or log an error on posting.  This would be a horrible place to detect sharing extensions.

I want to provide my users with the most flexible sharing experience but not at the cost of poor 3rd party implementation.

I know we like to show code on SO but can't think of any that isn't just boilerplate `UIActivityController` fodder.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's smart to do so, but you can setup a "whitelist" of trusted activity providers.  Then use UIActivityItemProvider with UIActivityItemSource protocol.  You'll get calls on:

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
     itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
```

Check the `activityType`.  If it's on your whitelist of trusted providers, return the data item.  If the `activityType` isn't recognized, return nil (or return some neutered "safe" data element).

*Untrusted activities may still show up in the Activity sheet, but they won't get data with which to cause a problem for your app.*

Answer (score -4):

Is it possible to block all 3rd party sharing extensions?

Yes, possible. But through private API.
I can't tell you details, but it is possible.